Question about chord nomenclature
I am a guitar player with somewhere between basic to intermediate knowledge of music theory. I just recently started to get interested in Jazz, watched some YouTube videos and began doing simple things. This is when I stumbled upon "The Real Book" with a large list of songs with their chords and melodies.
On the first song I see quite a few different ways to write seventh chords and I do not understand what a few of them mean:

The Gb7 chord which I see, is formed with the notes Gb-Bb-Db-E, but if I build the chord using triads the last note should be F which is called Gbmaj7. Why is that?


There should be one question per question.
Your second bullet is answered here: Standard format for jazz chord symbols
To your first bullet: a Gb7 chord has the notes Gb-Bb-Db-Fb. The last note is not E, it is F flat.
The kinds of chords that chord symbols are for, are built as stacks of thirds, not triads. A triad means a three-note stack of thirds, two thirds.
An interval of a third means a pair of notes where the other note is the first note's letter name plus two letter names. For example, a three-note stack of thirds starting from C something, will have:

root: C something (natural, flat, sharp, double-flat, double-sharp etc.)
third: E something (natural, flat, sharp, double-flat, double-sharp etc.)
fifth: G something (natural, flat, sharp, double-flat, double-sharp etc.)

A four-note stack of thirds starting from G something will have:

root: G something (natural, flat, sharp, double-flat, double-sharp etc.)
third: B something (natural, flat, sharp, double-flat, double-sharp etc.)
fifth: D something (natural, flat, sharp, double-flat, double-sharp etc.)
seventh: F something (natural, flat, sharp, double-flat, double-sharp etc.)

In a Gb7 chord, the seventh is a minor seventh, and to get that the "F something" has to be F flat. On a piano keyboard, F flat is played with the same key as E natural.

And on a guitar, it's the same fret.

@SergioRomero And often you'll encounter the question "Well if F flat and E natural are played the same way and sound the same, who cares if I spell the chord using the E instead? It's easier for me to think about." To which the answer is, as long as you know you're doing it, and you're not trying to teach anybody else music theory, fine. But if you're composing in staff notation, it might be easier for the player to recognize a Gb7 chord if spelled properly. But from time to time you see "real composers" like Beethoven "cheat" a bit, like if the context called for a C flat minor chord,

which would have double flats, spelling it as a B minor chord instead. But if you're going to "cheat," better to change the entire chord like that than just one member.
